# text to binary conversion matlab

Tags: text, binary

I need to import a text file into matlab and convert it into binary so that the final array that contains the binary value is in some integer format and not character format. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
fid = fopen('myFile.txt', 'r');
F = fread(fid, 'char=>uint32')'
```